# CSS - How to resize an image to fit an header of a webpage

Tags: html, css

[image]I am building a webpage that is divided into 3 sections, a header, a content area and a footer. Each marked up by a div and they all belong to a wrapper div.

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div id="logo"> 
                    <img id="headerimg" src="assets/media/logos/Full_H.png" />
                </div><!-- End of logo -->
                <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">navigation1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">navigation2</a></li>
        </ul>
                </div><!-- End of navigation -->
            </div><!-- End of header -->
            <div class="container">
                <p>This is a container.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                <p>This is a footer.</p>
            </div>  
    </div>  <!-- End of wrapper-->
```

The styling rules are as follows:

```
   * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: none;
    }
    #wrapper {
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            width: 960px;
            /*width: 96%;*/ /* Holding outermost DIV */
            }
     #header {
        /* margin-bottom: 10p;*/
            width: 940px;
                    height: 80px;
                    outline:green dashed;
        }
     #logo {    
                   height: 60px;
                   width: 100%;
                   outline:blue dashed;
     } /*logo - End*/
```

I am trying to fit the image, Full_H.png, to the top left corner of the page without losing aspect ratio and confined to the header div only. The size of this image is 450 x 50, yet when I run this code the image is not confined to the header, it overflows. Can someone tell me how to contain the image to the size of the div without losing the image's quality? Thank you. Please let me know if my information is inadequate.

Comment: Yes, I you could provide an image of output, we might get the idea of problem clearly.

Comment: If your image's height is 50px and your div's height is 60px, the image shouldn't overflow in the y-axis.... I have tried, it's working fine. You need to elaborate your problem a little more to make your goal clear.